# Extjs - multi upload file

Tags: extjs, file-upload, upload, extjs4.1

I'm working well with **single upload** file **using PHP**. Now i'm doing with **multi upload** file. 
I found a question **[Why don't added records appear in grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587382/why-dont-added-records-appear-in-grid)** maybe it's the best multi upload file i found. My code here **http://jsfiddle.net/VQQea/**

```
                    var form = Ext.getCmp('form').getForm();
                    if(form.isValid()){ 
                        form.submit({
                             method: 'POST',
                             url: 'example.php',
                             success: function(fp, o) {
                             }
                        });
                    }else {
                        alert('fail'); 
                    }
```

But I don't know php file like how. 
Can anybody tell me a php file to upload multi file above thanks so much:).

**Edit:** 
My below code will upload last file (not multi files :( ). How can i upload multi file thanks.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['fileuploadfield-1017-inputEl'])) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['fileuploadfield-1017-inputEl']['name'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileuploadfield-1017-inputEl']['tmp_name'];

        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file_name);

        echo "{success:true}";
    }else {
        echo "{failure:true}";  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.MultiFile', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.File',
    alias: 'widget.multifilefield',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.on('render', function () {
            me.fileInputEl.set({ multiple: true });
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onFileChange: function (button, e, value) {
        this.duringFileSelect = true;

        var me = this,
            upload = me.fileInputEl.dom,
            files = upload.files,
            names = [];

        if (files) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                names.push(files[i].name);
            value = names.join(', ');
        }

        Ext.form.field.File.superclass.setValue.call(this, value);

        delete this.duringFileSelect;
    }
});
```

Live demo of multiple upload for ExtJS 4.2.2 is [here](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-2-2-html-5-multi-file-upload.html)